# Compile error in MKStoreKit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, mkstorekit

I'm getting an error:

> Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^)(NSString
>   *_*strong)' to parameter of type 'void (^)(NSString **_strong, NSData *__strong)'

When I'm implementing `MKStoreKit 4.3` in my app on the line of onComplete:

```
-(IBAction)purchaseFull {
    [[MKStoreManager sharedManager] buyFeature:@"productID"
                                onComplete:^(NSString* purchasedFeature)
    {
         NSLog(@"Purchased: %@", purchasedFeature);
         //purchaseBtn.hidden = YES;
    }
    onCancelled:^
    {
        NSLog(@"User Cancelled Transaction");
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [API you are trying to use](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKStoreKit/blob/master/MKStoreManager.h) has a method like this:

```objc
// use this method to invoke a purchase
- (void) buyFeature: (NSString*) featureId         
         onComplete: (void (^)(NSString* purchasedFeature, 
                               NSData* purchasedReceipt)) completionBlock
        onCancelled: (void (^)(void)) cancelBlock;
```

but, for the `completionBlock` parameter, you're passing

```objc
^(NSString* purchasedFeature) {
      NSLog(@"Purchased: %@", purchasedFeature);             
      //purchaseBtn.hidden = YES;        
}
```

which means you are missing the second (`NSData*`) parameter.

Change your code to something like this:

```objc
^(NSString* purchasedFeature, NSData* purchasedReceipt) {
      NSLog(@"Purchased: %@", purchasedFeature);             
      //purchaseBtn.hidden = YES;        
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, MKStoreKit seems to be documented in a very bad way, the code I used above was the one MKStoreKit author suggested on their blog!

Comment: @XIII, yeah they probably changed the API at some point, and never bothered to update the blog :(

Answer (score 3):

the answer for the new [API](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKStoreKit/blob/master/MKStoreManager.h):

```
 [[MKStoreManager sharedManager]
 buyFeature:kFeatureAId
 onComplete:^(NSString* purchasedFeature, NSData*purchasedReceipt, NSArray* availableDownloads)
 {
       NSLog(@"Purchased: %@", purchasedFeature);
 }
 onCancelled:^
 {
     NSLog(@"User Cancelled Transaction");
 }
 ];
```